# How to clone two functions in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I`m a new one in Jquery,so I have a prob with it.

```
  var element = $(ui.draggable).clone();
```

this one works pretty fine ,but how can i add resizable function to it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are referring to the jQuery UI function (http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/), and if that's the case then you would simply write:

```
element.resizable();
```

The above code would simply make the clone resizable. But don't forget you still need to add it to the DOM to have the user see and interact with it.